# cobalt built with asan can't start up

Tags: cobalt

we build cobalt(RELEASE_9) with asan by "-fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer " on our target(arm).
but our target is not powerful, CPU has 4 core with clock 1GHz.

but cobalt always quit after render Youtube logo(red UI).
we found cobalt always got 
"h5vcc://network-failure?retry-url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Ftv%3Fwired%3D1%26launch%3Dmenu%26additionalDataUrl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A40167%2
FdialData%3Fapp%3DYouTube%26env_isVideoInfoVisibl" 
in cobalt::browser::H5vccURLHandler::HandleURL()

could you give us some suggestion how cobalt can start properly with asan?

Comment: Quad-core device is more than enough to run Cobalt, with ASAN or without it.

Comment: Can you please tell which build of Cobalt are you running and whether all of your NPLB tests pass successfully.

Comment: yes, NPLB tests pass successfully.

Comment: without asan, cobalt can start and work properly.

Comment: Can you please file an issue at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=181120&template=699202 , so that we can continue conversation there? Please make sure to follow the template.